# Transient login failures to SQL Server "Cannot open database "*****" requested by the login. The login failed."

Tags: java, sql-server, pentaho, pentaho-data-integration

I have a nightly ETL routine (PDI - Pentaho Data Integration which is Java based) that connects to various data sources and pulls data to manipulate and load into another database. Without changing the code, I'll occasionally have a job fail due to receiving a login failure against my SQL Server database. The error received is:

> Cannot open database "*****" requested by the login. The login failed.

The credentials are stored in a text file which does not change. I can simply re-run the job and everything works perfectly fine.

SQL Server reports in its error log the login failure. I can confirm the user has access to the database specified by logging in as that user via SSMS to the SQL Server directly.

[image]

**Key components in software stack are...**

- Server 1: Ubuntu 14.04

  - Pentaho Data Integration 7.1
  - mssql-jdbc-6.2.0.jre8.jar
  - Java 1.8.0_60
- Server 2: Windows Server 2008 R2

  - SQL Server 2012 Express

What could cause this inconsistency with login failures? Is there a reasonable method to log the credentials being used to access the database so I can better determine where the source of the issue lies?

Comment: Change the database(s) to auto close false.

Answer (score 1):

If the database you're trying to connect to is also the one that is starting up in that log then that could be the problem. https://www.brentozar.com/blitz/auto-close-enabled/.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. That is the case, but the question would be: Why doesn't this happen all the time to other databases as well? I have all my databases with `AutoClose` set to `True`. I also didn't see any indication in the blog post that the issue I described would be caused by `AutoClose=True`

Comment: I'm not entirely sure why you do not see this all the time but if I were to make an educated guess, it could be due to the frequency of the connections in combination with any lag in the DB starting up. In that screenshot we can see the DB starting up at 7:41:14 and the connection failing at 7:41:16 which I think means that the DB had not started up by 7:41:16 - a full 2 seconds later...

Comment: I would avoid setting DB options without knowing what they actually do (guess this wasn't you though!) and Microsoft docs are getting much better and accessible for reading up on this kind of stuff. Microsoft also helpfully mention you can get timeouts, https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/2160685/recommendations-and-guidelines-for-setting-the-auto-close-database-opt, due to this setting

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem a few years ago. It happen that IS was closing the database connection during the night for cleanup and other maintenance tasks.

The solution was an automatic restart 1/2 hour after in case of error. Do not try more than 5 restart trial, though, because in this case the problem is probably else were.